# If a watch battery that has not been used for 7 years gets reinstalled and is new, what are the chances of it working?

Tags: power-supply, batteries

I have a watch last used in 2014 with a new watch cell battery. However, the cell lost good contact with the watch connectors. Would the battery still be good upon reinstallation with a good connection? With another watch, I have secured a loose battery successfully in a watch before. Given the time gap factor, I need to know whether or not the battery would still be good. My watch I am referring to is a CASIO watch. The battery model is a CR1616 cell. This watch has been not taking any of the battery's power supply since 2014. Any assistance would be helpful.

Comment: Try it and see. Or take a voltmeter to the battery while you have it out. If it's no good, a replacement is $1.

Comment: your question makes no sense ... what use is an answer such as `good chance`?

Comment: The shelf life of primary lithium cells is on the order of 10 years. So even if the watch has been drawing zero power for most of that time, you're still nearing the end of that period.

Comment: Measure the voltage, If it's below 3V there may not be much life left in it.

Answer (score 2):

Most batteries including lithium coin cells have self discharge. This is caused by the internal chemical reactions of the battery components. When fresh from the factory they have about 10 years before they are considered below a standard of capacity for "good" usage. If they have been used then the amount of time before they are "no good" will be reduced accordingly. It's not a set or linear rate. Add to this other issues like leaking, or passivation (building up a resistive layer due to lack of use that causes initial poor power capacity).

Essentially the battery may be bad. It may not. Test it under load to see what voltage curve you get over time.

Answer (score 0):

It may work, but there's no way to tell for how long.  I recently needed to change a watch battery, but discovered that the expiry date on my packet of batteries was Dec 2014.

I found a battery that wasn't leaking, and it works for now.